# How can I find my particle system?

Tags: modifiers, interface, particles

I feel very stupid asking this .... but uh ... I have this brick wall and I gave one of those bricks a particle system. But now I don't know any more which brick. How can I find the brick with the particle system ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open the *Outliner*
2. Switch it's mode to *Current Scene*
3. Use the search box to search for `ParticleSystem` by default (or whichever other name you used, if you manually renamed it)
4. You object with the particle system should come up in the list bellow
5. Just click on its icon and it should select the relevant object in the 3D view